# How to correct the "yaw" behavior of a quadrotor when crossing the angles' limits?

Tags: ros, quadcopter, quaternion, yaw

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

My quadrotor has a strange behavior ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6Trr7d4iro)) when it turns around 180° (the returned value of atan2()). After investigating for hours I 'm pretty sure I found what the problem.
Referring to this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher) as a reference I realized that the angle around the vertical axis (which in my quadrotor is exactly the same structure, see my code [here](http://pastebin.com/dzRp42m3) from line 34) , in the tutorial expressed as *angle* :

```
tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(angle+M_PI/2);
```

is simply added by a small quantity calculated at each pass and doesn't take care of the fact that for angles bigger than 180° (or smaller than -180°) the corresponding quaternion has the same value 8or the same orientation if you prefer). In other words, the method  `tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw` is going to calculate the correct value even if the angles is crossing those *limits*.

The nagle in my application jumps about the Z-axis from the positive sector to the negative (and viceversa) because the returned value from atan2() is outputting *right* values but with the *wrong* interpretation. As you can see, in the following output (all values are in degree for simplify):

```
...  
Yaw: -164.3665  
Yaw: -174.0903 
Goal reached 
Moving to the 3 waypoint  
Yaw: 172.8751  
Yaw: 161.7627  
Yaw: 153.9304  
Yaw: 148.2633 
Yaw: 144.0085 
...
```

is clear that the quadrotor must move its nose from -174° to + 172°. But instead of to take the shortest way to to that, it turns counterclockwise along the longest path.
I think that this is the normal behavior of `tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw()` which doesn't consider the shortest way to reach the next angle, but it output the corresponding quaternion to that value 8could I have a confirmation about that?)

**Now:** one could say:  "get rid of an absolut coordinate system for your quadrotor and calculate the angle about the Z-axis as a variable, which is going to be changed by small increments every time your code runs a loop...exact like in the tutorial you mentioned!!!"

That's what I thought at the beginning, but I have the problem that all the position and attitude controller for quadrotor are using a fixed coordinate system for their calculation:

[image: image description]

Resume:
I want to correct the behavior of my quadrotor about the Z-axis.
To do that I could:

- Rewrite all my controllers for attitude and position to use a body coordinate system and treating the yaw a variable which increments by small changes in orientation without taking care about the limits I said above -> I ve really no idea how to rewrite my code to use such a *variable change* and  I think it would lead to new problems;
- Use two "yaws": one absolut for the controllers and the other one "locally" which is going to be passed to the method `tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw()`. As above...I ve no idea how to implement it in my code;

What would you do guys? Could you me point to the right direction or give my the most used solution?

PS: Even mapping the output of atan2() to 0-360° doesn't change anything. It *moves* simply the problem between 0 and 360°

I hope my question is clear. If not tell me please and I'll update the question.

Merry Christmas !!
Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199989/how-to-correct-the-%22yaw%22-behavior-of-a-quadrotor-when-crossing-the-angles%27-limits?!?!/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2014-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What format you store the angular positions in does not change the wrapping problem on a unit circle. You need to have an algorithm which computes wrapping the appropriate way for your applications.

The [angles](http://wiki.ros.org/angles) has some of the most common algorithms for this. In particular I suggest you look at the [shortet_angular_distance](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/angles/html/namespaceangles.html#a83debbedd331511aa914f393db576818) method.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1